# Determine which set is from a different distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing, python

I am given 5 sets of data and I know one of them is different from the rest. How would I go about identifying which one. The sample sizes and variances are different. The datasets are greater than 10,000 elements.

I calculated the mean and standard deviation for each of the sets, and one of the sets is very different. I want to statistically prove that the difference is significant.

I tried to do a welch t test using python with the following function:

```
scipy.stats.ttest_ind(a, b, equal_var=False)
```

but the p-values are very low for everything (ex. low like 1e-21).

I'm not sure why the welch t-test is not working and if another method is more suitable.

Comment: The P-value (very nearly 0 and certainly <0.05=5%) shows strong evidence that the null hypothesis (equal means) as rejected at any reasonable level of significance. What result did you anticipate the Welch test would give? // It would help to know what kind of data you have (integers? continuous scale?)  Also, what size and kind of differences btw datasets are you looking for? With samples as large as 10,000 you have good power to detect even tiny differences that may not be of importance to you. Please give more context and information.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. My data is continuous floating point numbers. From the 5 sample sets (each over 10,000 elements), 4 of them has a range between -300 and +300. Mean is approx 3-5 and std approx 40-50 for 4/5 samples. One of the samples has mean of 25 and std of 130 with a range of -500 and +1000. So I can visually see the problem here. I am looking for a method to show that this difference is statistically significant with some confidence.

Comment: In the situation you describe, you may need to do tests for equal variances instead of Welch test which compares means. But I fear you may be missing the point. You keep on saying "statistical significance," possibly without understanding what that terminology really means. // With large enough $n$ you can tell the difference btw a coin with P(Heads) = 0.5000 and a coin with P(Heads) = 0.5001 and that difference would be real. But for purposes of deciding which team defends which goal there is no practical importance btw the two coins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two datasets that may be essentially the same for practical purposes, but are
found to be different by Welch two-sample t test:

```
    set.seed(904)
    x1 = rnorm(10000, 1001, 15)
    x2 = rnorm(10000, 1002, 15)
    t.test(x1, x2)

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  x1 and x2
t = -4.6203, df = 19998, p-value = 3.856e-06
alternative hypothesis: 
  true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
  -1.3913997 -0.5624911
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 1001.138  1002.115 

boxplot(x1, x2, col="skyblue2", pch=20)
```

[image]

If you're mainly interested in differences large enough to be obvious
from looking at summary statistics or boxplots, then maybe just do
a visual inspection.

```
x3 = rnorm(10000, 1000, 15)
x4 = rnorm(10000, 1020, 15)
x5 = rnorm(10000, 999, 15)

boxplot(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, col="skyblue2", pch=20, names=T)
```

[image]

*Addendum:* Now that you have given approximate means and SDs, I'll try another example.

```
set.seed(2020)
y1 = rnorm(10000, 2, 40)
y2 = rnorm(10000, 3.5, 40)
y3 = rnorm(10000, 4.5, 40)
y4 = rnorm(10000, 25, 130)
y5 = rnorm(10000, 5.5, 40)
boxplot(y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, col="skyblue2", pch=20, names=T)
```

Boxplots show clearly that Group 4 differs from the others.

[image]

Some of the Welch t tests will detect the relatively small (perhaps unimportant) differences between means of Groups 1, 2, 3, and 5; with P-values below 5%.

```
 t.test(y1,y2)$p.val
 [1] 0.00703525
 t.test(y2,y5)$p.val
 [1] 0.003545032
```

However, group variances are all the same---except for Group 4. So you
will mostly not find differences in variances among Groups 1, 2, 3, and 5.
And you should find different variances between Group 4 and one of the other groups.

```
var.test(y1, y2)

        F test to compare two variances

data:  y1 and y2
F = 0.96727, num df = 9999, denom df = 9999, p-value = 0.09614
alternative hypothesis: true ratio of variances is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.9300803 1.0059402
sample estimates:
ratio of variances 
         0.9672668 

var.test(y1,y4)

         F test to compare two variances

data:  y1 and y4
F = 0.094033, num df = 9999, denom df = 9999, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true ratio of variances is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
  0.09041748 0.09779217
sample estimates:
ratio of variances 
        0.09403255
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would there be a way to determine if the difference is statistically significant to come to a conclusion?

Comment: Each group is sampled from a different population. Means $\mu = 1001, 1002, 1000, 1020, 999,$ respectively. For samples of sizes $n=10\,000,$ a Welch test will find a _**statistically significant difference**_ between any two samples. However, in some real-world application you may feel that Sample 4 from population with $\mu=1020$ is the only difference of _**practical importance.**_ The point of my Comment and Answer is that you have to understand the distinction between statistical significance and practical importance.// Tests with only $n = 100$ would give different results. Try it.

Comment: Please see my Addendum.